# How can I create a list of random numbers and make sure there are no duplicates for a C# lottery program?

Tags: c#

Im a student who is just a beginner at programming and i was tasked with a lottery program where I need to generate `6` random integers and make sure that they are all unique.

Comment: Create a List of ints. Use Math Random to add to list if dont exist

Comment: Asking "Is there a way to X?" or "Can somebody help me?" questions could have a "yes/no" answer that is perfectly valid yet it is no very useful. Check the help section and especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The question could use some editing, but it was clear enough for someone to give a  good answer.

Comment: @ScottHannen it should have beend edited indeed, but it was answered and imho it was a good answer.

Comment: @bradbury9 - sorry, careless choice of words. I meant that it was clear enough that someone was able to give a good answer, since Dmitry did.

Comment: Im sorry i will put more effort to my questions in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exploit `HashSet<int>` to ensure that items are unique, e.g.

```
  Random rnd = new Random();

  ...

  int maxValue = 100;

  HashSet<int> items = new HashSet<int>();

  // 6 random unique (no duplicates) items in [0..maxValue) range
  while (items.Count < 6) 
    items.Add(rnd.Next(maxValue));

  // If you insist on having List<int> (not HashSet<int>), let's create it:
  List<int> result = new List<int>(items);
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question and helping me out.